# How to enumerate a .csv file in python?

Tags: python, csv

I have a byCCD.csv file which contains like

```
1,2014-08-18,India,3
1,2014-08-18,United States,2
1,2014-08-24,India,2
1,2014-08-24,United States,0
```

I have a Python function to parse the .csv file

```
 def parseCCDfile():
    with open('byCCD.csv', 'rb') as f:
      reader = csv.reader(f)
      for r, row in enumerate(reader):
         for id, d, ccd, cnt in enumerate(row):
            # logic for parsing the file
```

I am getting error as : ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
Please help to correct this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are already looping over each row, you don't need to loop over the *columns* either.

Remove the line:

```
for id, d, ccd, cnt in enumerate(row):
```

because looping over the row produces *one* value at a time, plus the `enumerate()` index.

You can instead assign those values in the other loop:

```
for r, (id, d, ccd, cnt) in enumerate(reader):
```

or use a tuple assignment:

```
for r, row in enumerate(reader):
    id, d, ccd, cnt = row
```